# Regex to extract part of string before regex match

Tags: java, regex

Say i have the following line:

```
My '123? Text – 56x73: Hello World blablabla
```

I want to extract everything before " - 56x73 ..."

I already found a regex to match the part which I don't want to extract:

```
\s–\s\d{1,2}x\d{1,2}:\s.+
```

How can I get only the other part using Java and Regex?

Comment: Did you try prepending `(.+)` to the regex??

Comment: You can replace part which you don't want with empty string: `result = text.replaceAll("yourRegex","")`.

Comment: `String res = text.replaceFirst("\\s*[-–]\\s*\\d{1,2}x\\d{1,2}:\\s.+", "");`, see http://ideone.com/CDxM6n

Comment: Using `replaceAll("\\s–\\s\\d{1,2}x\\d{1,2}:\\s.+", "")` did the trick thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
String str= ...
String regex= your regex

Pattern pattern;
Matcher matcher;

pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

if (matcher.find())
{
matcher.group(0, 1, ...)
```

use () in your regex to deliminate groups

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

You already got way around but this can be helpful,
Assuming 56 and 73 will NOT be constant.

Use Regex: `"(.*)(\\s)(.*)(\\s)([\\d]+[x][\\d]+)"`

then use "group(int number)" where a number will be 1 in this case.
I used .* between two \s intentionally to get around with "-" thing I didn't anything about that but I found [this](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/dashes.html). Also noticed from one of the comment.

If anybody wants to edit and improve my answer you are more than welcome.